# Smash 4 DLC Codes

Tags: super-smash-bros-4, nintendo-eshop

So my friend has some eShop credit left in his account, and I'd like to get Ryu, but I have no eShop credit. Can my friend buy Ryu then send me the code for me to use? Or is the code linked to the account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code can be redeemed by anyone as stated on the [Nintendo eShop FAQ.](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12470/~/faq---nintendo-eshop-purchases-through-nintendo.com)

Answer (score 0):

The code that you get when you buy any dlc can be used on any account but may only be used once.